# How to fix autoload warning after update Laravel

Tags: laravel-4, composer-php

`C:\Users\User-PC>composer dump-autoload`

**How fix problem after update Laravel with command composer self-update?**

Composer could not find a composer.json file in `C:\Users\User-PC`
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the
http://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section

Comment: Looks like your `composer.phar` is not in the same folder as your `composer.json`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`composer self-update` is for updating composer not for updating laravel. So if you want to update laravel you need to run `composer update` (inside the laravel dir)